# To search a particular word in textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to search a particular word in text area and replace it with another word.

**How to do this in java script reg ex ?**

```
res.replaceAll("(?i)(hello)", "\\*$1\\*"); have tried this.
```

Comment: Please post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a global replace, but javascript has no `replaceAll`, instead you'll have to use regex with the global modifier and a capturing group to add the asterix

```
res = res.replace(/(hello)/g, '*$1*');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fLvvx/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "this is a this";
s = s.replace(/this/g, "test");

//result will be "test is a test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
res.replace(/\bword here\b/g,"another word");
```

Word boundary will match only particular word.

Answer (score 0):

For that you don't need to use regex you can simply do it by **replace** method

```
val = $('textarea').html() ;
val = val.replace("oldword","newword");
$('textarea').html(val);
```

else  if u want to do it via **regex**  use

```
var str= "new word";
$('textarea').html(str.replace(/new/g, "old")); 
}
```

[LIVE example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDk9J/)